# Which cryptographic functionality is in Gitea version 1.19.3?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, gitea

For legal reasons, I would like to understand whether or not there is non-standard cryptography in Gitea version 1.19.3.
Here, "non-standard" means any implementation of “cryptography” involving the incorporation or use of proprietary or unpublished cryptographic functionality, including encryption algorithms or protocols that have not been adopted or approved by a duly recognized international standards body (e.g., IEEE, IETF, ISO, ITU, ETSI, 3GPP, TIA, and GSMA) and have not otherwise been published.

Thanks

I searched for this information on the https://docs.gitea.com/ site, but couldn't find a clear statement.

Comment: All the algorithms are standard and documented in standards (at least via the IETF).  However, the specification of some of the SSH algorithms for use in SSH specifically is not standardized.  However, this is practically true for everyone using SSH these days, including OpenSSH.  That being said, if you need legal advice, you need a lawyer, and I am not one.